# How to print part of item in a list?

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like this:

```
['Blake 4', 'Bolt 1', 'De Grasse 3', 'Gatlin 2', 'Simbine 5', 'Youssef Meite 6']
```

I am trying to print this:

```
Blake
Bolt
De Grasse
Gatlin
Simbine
Youssef Meite
```

How do I go about writing a list comprehension that handles this scenario? I tried using `split` and indexing but nothing I have used has worked.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that bats is asking for help :O

Comment: I'm new to coding and am trying to get the hang of it :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all the values keep that pattern, split and join back, ignoring last value in splitted array:

```
l = ['Blake 4', 'Bolt 1', 'De Grasse 3', 'Gatlin 2', 'Simbine 5', 'Youssef Meite 6']
for x in l:
   print(' '.join(x.split()[:-1]))
```

Otherwise, use regex to eliminate numerals:

```
import re
l = ['Blake 4', 'Bolt 1', 'De Grasse 3', 'Gatlin 2', 'Simbine 5', 'Youssef Meite 6']
for x in l:
    print(re.sub(' \d+', '', x))
```

Answer (score 1):

list comprehension is useless to *print* stuff (or any operations where you don't need the return value).

In your case, you could use `str.rpartition` in a loop to print only the left hand of the rightmost space found in the string:

```
l =['Blake 4', 'Bolt 1', 'De Grasse 3', 'Gatlin 2', 'Simbine 5', 'Youssef Meite 6']
for s in l:
    print(s.rpartition(" ")[0])
```

Just stripping the last digit off the list would be a good usage of listcomp:

```
newl = [s.rpartition(" ")[0] for s in l]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
l = ['Blake 4', 'Bolt 1', 'De Grasse 3', 'Gatlin 2', 'Simbine 5', 'Youssef Meite 6']
for i in l:
    print(i[:-2])
```

Indexing is sufficient for solving your problem.

Based on @Jean-François 's comment, if you are trying to remove all the characters before the last space, you can do this instead:

```
l = ['Blake 4', 'Bolt 1', 'De Grasse 3', 'Gatlin 2', 'Simbine 5', 'Youssef Meite 6']
for i in l:
    print(i[:-i[::-1].index(' ')-1])
```

Comment: what guarantees that the values won't be above 9?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Absolutely valid point. But we don't have enough information about what the data looks like. My answer is only based on the sample list he provides.